# RPM Build Error: File must begin with "/"

Tags: linux, centos, redhat, rpm, rpmbuild

Here is my spec file: http://pastebin.com/MtzxC1kv

When I try to run `rpmbuild -ba myfile.spec`, I get the following errors:

```
+ /usr/lib/rpm/brp-python-bytecompile
+ /usr/lib/rpm/redhat/brp-java-repack-jars
Processing files: PA_Connector-1.0-1.0
error: File must begin with "/": %{_initddir}/pa_connector
error: File must begin with "/": attr(755,impulse,impulse)
error: File must begin with "/": attr(644,impulse,impulse)
error: File must begin with "/": attr(644,impulse,impulse)
error: File must begin with "/": attr(644,impulse,impulse)
error: File must begin with "/": attr(644,impulse,impulse)
error: File must begin with "/": attr(644,impulse,impulse)
error: File must begin with "/": attr(644,impulse,impulse)
Checking for unpackaged file(s): /usr/lib/rpm/check-files /var/tmp/PA_Connector-1.0-1.0-root
error: Installed (but unpackaged) file(s) found:
   /%{_initddir}/pa_connector
   /opt/pa_connector/config.xml
   /opt/pa_connector/lib/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar
   /opt/pa_connector/lib/log4j-1.2.17.jar
   /opt/pa_connector/lib/pa_connector.jar
   /opt/pa_connector/log4j.properties
   /opt/pa_connector/pa_connector.sh


RPM build errors:
    File must begin with "/": %{_initddir}/pa_connector
    File must begin with "/": attr(755,impulse,impulse)
    File must begin with "/": attr(644,impulse,impulse)
    File must begin with "/": attr(644,impulse,impulse)
    File must begin with "/": attr(644,impulse,impulse)
    File must begin with "/": attr(644,impulse,impulse)
    File must begin with "/": attr(644,impulse,impulse)
    File must begin with "/": attr(644,impulse,impulse)
    Installed (but unpackaged) file(s) found:
   /%{_initddir}/pa_connector
   /opt/pa_connector/config.xml
   /opt/pa_connector/lib/commons-logging-1.1.1.jar
   /opt/pa_connector/lib/log4j-1.2.17.jar
   /opt/pa_connector/lib/pa_connector.jar
   /opt/pa_connector/log4j.properties
   /opt/pa_connector/pa_connector.sh
```

I've read a few posts on SO about correct what BuildRoot should be, and fixed it, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Unfortunately the OP's initial spec file is no longer available, so some of the context required to understand the approved answer is now missing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like `_initddir` is not defined, or it would be expanded out in the final filename, and you seem to have a file named "`/%{_initddir}/pa_connector`" .

Also, you need a `%` in front of `attr` to use the `%attr` macro.